# Trying to save a list with saveAll(). It doesn't work and no exception is thrown

Tags: java, jpa

I'm creating a service that basically gets an xlsx file. Eead all this file and creates an object for each row. Then return a list of objects that has been created. After that I save this list with the saveAll() method. But I'm having a problem saving it. The JPA doesn't execute the save function but doesn't inform me any error.

When debugging, it stops at the following line.

[image]

Here is the method where I read and return the list of objects created from the file

```
 public static List<Measure> excelToMeasures(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    List<Measure> measures = new ArrayList<Measure>();

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

    int rowNumber = 0;
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        // skip header
        if (rowNumber == 0) {
            rowNumber++;
            continue;
        }

        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();

        Measure measure = new Measure();

        int cellIdx = 0;
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            switch (cellIdx) {
                case 0:
                    measure.setCode(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;


                case 1:
                    measure.setBehavior(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;

                case 2:
                    measure.setMeasureType(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    System.out.println(measure.getMeasureType());
                    break;

                case 3:
                    measure.setValue(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    System.out.println(measure.getValue());
                    break;

            }
            cellIdx++;
        }
        measures.add(measure);
    }
    workbook.close();
    return measures;
}
```

And here is the part of the code where I try to save the list.

```
    public List<Measure> save(MultipartFile file) {

    try {

        List<Measure> measures = ExcelHelper.excelToMeasures(file.getInputStream());

        repository.saveAll(measures);
        return  measures;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("fail to store excel data: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public List<Measure> getAllMeasures() {
    return repository.findAll();
}
```

}

Any idea the reason why it is not being saved?

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean with "When debugging, it stops at the following line"? Also I guess you verify nothing is saved by looking at the database, right? When do you do that?

Comment: After repository.saveAll(measures); call repository.flush()

Comment: Make sure your service/calls are running inside a transaction boundary. Most days if you have a framework managing your JPA entity manager, this involves just putting a @Transactional around the method it exists in or in a method that ultimately calls.

Comment: Replace your while loop with return this.saveAll(entities);